# Changing date at browser level for testing

Tags: testing, browser

Is there a simple way to test something showing up between two dates by changing the date in the browser (similar to spoofing the time zone in Chrome dev tools) - hoping to avoid changing the date on my whole system to do it.

This is for QA testing not automated tests.